# MS SQL Server 2019 в nodejs доступен по адресу localhost, как поменять на действительное имя сервера

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

В MS SQL Mangment studio я могу подключиться к серверу по имени `CompName\SQLEXPRESS`, но когда я создаю соединение с сервером в NodeJS (Sequalize):

```js
new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'mssql',
        host: 'CompName\\SQLEXPRESS', //- не работает, localhost - работает
        port: 1433,
        username: 'name',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database',
      });
```

то выдает ошибку:

```bsh
equelizeHostNotFoundError: Failed to connect to CompName\SQLEXPRESS:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND CompName\SQLEXPRESS
```

Как можно изменить имя сервера для подключения в NodeJS?

P.S.: TCP/IP на сервере включил
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

При подключении к именованному экземпляру, не нужно указывать его в host, так как это сетевое имя и при подключении, dns сервер пытается разрезолвить host с именем `CompName\\SQLEXPRESS` который вряд ли есть в вашей сети. Для именнованных каналов у Sequelize есть `dialectOptions`. Будет как-то так

```
new Sequelize({
        dialect: 'mssql',
        host: 'CompName', //или localhost
        port: 1433,
        username: 'name',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'database',
        dialectOptions: {
            options: { instanceName: "SQLEXPRESS" }
        }
});
```

Comment: @xzdwq пожалуйста, поставьте галку "ответ принят", если он вам помог. это сделает возможным ссылаться на ответ при закрытии похожих вопросов