# Подключение к экземпляру SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Имеется следующий код с официального сайта майкрософт:

```
const Connection = require("tedious").Connection

const config = {
    server: "175.18.3.127\TEST3", //update me
    authentication: {
        type: "default",
        options: {
            userName: "login", //update me
            password: "password", //update me
        },
    },
    options: {
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        database: "TestDB", //update me
    },
}

const connection = new Connection(config)

connection.on("connect", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log("Connected")
    }
})

connection.connect()

const dbMS = connection
```

Не подключается к БД с ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База расположена на локальном сервере. При этом, этот же код прекрасно работает для подключения к БД, созданной на моем пк

Также смущает, что прописывая адрес: 175.18.3.127\TEST3, в ошибке он отображается как: 175.18.3.127TEST3

Если прописать только первую часть адреса: 175.18.3.127, то ошибка будет такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также без проблем можно подключиться к БД через SQL Management Studio

Comment: Ну, вероятно, один слэш в строковом литерале воспринимается как квотирование следующего символа. Попробуй его удвоить - ```server: "175.18.3.127\\TEST3"```

Comment: Удваивал, та же ошибка getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: Не, в строке ошибки теперь отображается `ENOTFOUND 175.18.3.127\TEST3` или по-прежнему без слэша? PS. "Имеется следующий код с официального сайта майкрософт" - ссылку добавьте.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/connect/node-js/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-node-js?view=sql-server-ver16 добавляя 2 слэша, адрес в ошибке отображается с 1 слэшем

Comment: По указанной ссылке я вижу ```server: 'your_server.database.windows.net',  //update me``` - то есть только DNS-адрес сервера, а не IP-адрес, и уж тем более не вижу там слэша с именем базы данных... мы точно в одну и ту же веб-страницу смотрим?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGO2k.png

Comment: 175.18.3.127\TEST3 - TEST3 не имя БД, а полное имя сервера, по которому я подключаюсь через management studio, имя БД - TestDB

Comment: ??? Вот теперь непонятно от слова "вообще". 175.18.3.127 - это чей IP-адрес? TEST3 - это NetBIOS-имя, что ли? Тогда оставьте только его, а IP и слэш уберите.

Comment: TEST3 - это экземпляр. Из гугла: "В MS SQL старше 2000 введено понятие экземпляра (instance) MS SQL. Т.е. на одном компе может стоять несколько MS SQL и различаются они по имени экземпляра."

Comment: Статья датирована 26.09.2022... т.е. явно после описанного нововведения. В любом случае Вы получаете отлуп от функции getaddrinfo - общей функции, которая знать не знает про MS SQL вообще и про его инстансы в частности, так что неудивительно, что Вы получаете ошибку. Думаю, что Вы в неверном месте размещаете имя инстанса - он должен быть обработан явно самим SQL Server после первичного подключения. Так что скорее ему место в параметре database... с другой стороны, инстанс нужен для правильной аутентификации... в общем, получается, что данная статья к Вашему случаю просто неприменима.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MS SQL Server 2019 в nodejs доступен по адресу localhost, как поменять на действительное имя сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303002/ms-sql-server-2019-%d0%b2-nodejs-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83-localhost-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением TEST3, не в server, а в options конфига:

```
const config = {
    server: "175.18.3.127", // ТОЛЬКО АДРЕС
    authentication: {
        type: "default",
        options: {
            userName: "login",
            password: "password",
        },
    },
    options: {
        instanceName: 'TEST3' // ИМЯ ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРА
        trustServerCertificate: true,
        database: "TestDB",
    },
}
```